# what is the different about Null and null in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Today I am facing a problem about `type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'` in this code line in flutter(version 3.7.11):

```
String? username = await SecureStorageUtil.getString(GlobalConfig.getUserNameCachedKey());
```

and this is the `getString` function define:

```
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';

class SecureStorageUtil{

  static FlutterSecureStorage _preferences = FlutterSecureStorage();

  static Future<String?> getString (String key, {String defValue = ''}) {
    return _preferences.read(key:key) ;
  }

  static Future<void> putString(String key, String value) {
    return _preferences.write(key:key, value:value);
  }

  static Future<void> delString(String key) {
    return _preferences.delete(key:key);
  }
}
```

what should I do to handle this situation? I have tried this code block:

```
void main() {
  String? a = null;
}
```

it works, then this code block did not work:

```
void main() {
  String? a = Null;
}
```

Seems Null is a type and null is a value. But why this code `await SecureStorageUtil.getString(GlobalConfig.getUserNameCachedKey());` return a type? Am I missing something?

Comment: it's returning `null` the sole instance of the class `Null`.  The error message is noting the types involved, so of course it would say Null not null.

Comment: "But why this code await SecureStorageUtil.getString(GlobalConfig.getUserNameCachedKey()); return a type?" It doesn't return a type.  The error indicates that you're passing the *value* `null` where `String` is expected.  If you tried to pass, say, `false`, you'd get an error message `type 'bool' is not a subtype of type 'String'`.  Additionally, since `SecureStorageUtil.getString` returns a `Future<String?>`, the problem is not about what `getString` returns.  More likely the problem is that `GlobalConfig.getUserNameCachedKey()` is returning `null`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `async/await` when calling the read method

```
static Future<String?> getString (String key, {String defValue = ''}) async {
 return await _preferences.read(key:key) ; 
}
```

calling the method without the await keyword will return the value of type `Future<String?>` which is not `String` type

read more about Dart Future calls [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future-class.html)

if you want to return the `defValue` instead of `null` do this

```
static Future<String> getString (String key, {String defValue = ''}) async {
 return await _preferences.read(key:key) ?? defValue ; 
}
```